# How do to a nested for loop in this example with javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
var data = [
    {
    "something": "something",
    "stages": [{
                "node": {"name": "test0"},
                "status": {"name": "test"},
                "time": {"name": "test"}
               },{
                "node": {"name": "test1"},
                "status": {"name": "test"},
                "time": {"name": "test"}
               }]
     }
];

nodeList = []

data.forEach(obj =>
  obj.stages.forEach(stage => if (nodeList.indexOf(stage.node.name) > -1) {
   nodeList.push({stage.node.name})
  );
```

I am trying to add the name to a list if that name does not already exist in the list.  The above is not working.

Comment: The `in operator` gets you indexes. Use `of operator` of `this.job[0].stage[i]`.

Comment: `for(... in ...)` iterates through the keys in an object. In your example `i` is a _string_, not a stage.

Comment: Per JLRishe's comment, you possibly want `for (node in this.job[0].stage[i]) { console.log(node.name) }`. *i* is a property name, not a reference. You might also need `function nodeName() { ... } `.

Comment: this did not resolve the issue - I updated OP with a little more information

Comment: about a million syntax errors but that code you've updated in there is mostly right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For...in loops in javascript return strings, not objects. You can either continue treating it as a string, or parse it into an object to loop over.

Also totally confused about you redefining `i`, it's not going to work unless you make a different variable in your first loop

```
for (field in this.job[0].stages[i]) {
  console.log(field);
    for (node in this.job[0].stages[i][field]) {
      console.log(node);
      console.log(this.job[0].stages[i][field][node].name);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

here, from what you've put in the OP I've fixed your syntax errors

```
var data = [
  {
  "something": "something",
  "stages": [{
              "node": {"name": "test0"},
              "status": {"name": "test"},
              "time": {"name": "test"}
             },{
              "node": {"name": "test1"},
              "status": {"name": "test"},
              "time": {"name": "test"}
             }]
   }
];

nodeList = [];

data.forEach(obj =>
  obj.stages.forEach(stage => {
    if (nodeList.indexOf(stage.node.name) === -1) {
      return nodeList.push(stage.node.name)
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: so this seems like the most elegant solution - I tried it and could not get it working.  Then I realized the json example in OP was slightly out of order so I updated the json in the OP - hoping you can revise your answer to match this

Comment: what is i even? how does your line `this.job[0].stages[i]` work as you explained it did? `i` must be defined somewhere outside this function, right? If you don't want it then it would just be this answer without the `[i]` on lines 1, 3, and 5.

Comment: I added [i] because that was suggested in the answer below.  No idea what i is or does.  Hoping to find a solution

Comment: Ok well if it wasn't part of your original question then try this without the 3 i's on the lines i mentioned above. Your JSON in your question isn't real JSON in the first place (You're missing a closing bracket in each array value) so im just not really sure what you need here

Comment: I removed the i's and still does not work.  I had a lot of sensitive data in the json so could not do a copy and paste - but tried again to update it in the OP more accurately

Answer (score 0):

Why not try:

```
function nodeName () {
  if (this.job[ 0 ].stages[ 0 ]) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.job[ 0 ].stages.length; i++) {
      let name = this.job[ 0 ].stages[ i ].node.name
      if (name)
        console.log(name) // "test"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others were mentioning, the `i` is just a string in this case because it is the name of a key which is just a string. To get the value of `i` in your structure you need to fully reference the object using it again:

```
nodeName() {
  if (this.job[0].stages[0]) {
    for (i in this.job[0].stages[i]) {
      console.log(i);
      for (node in this.job[0].stages[i].node) {
        console.log(node.name)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the object literal you've added to the OP (and fixing the syntax errors), the data object is an array of objects which have a *stages* property.

*stages* is also an array of objects that have a *node* property, which is an object with a *name* property.

You shouldn't use *for..in* for arrays as the order is not guaranteed. Assuming that you need it to be, you should use *forEach*, which also makes the code much more concise:

```js
var data = [
    {
    "something": "something",
    "stages": [{
                "node": {"name": "test0"},
                "status": {"name": "test"},
                "time": {"name": "test"}
               },{
                "node": {"name": "test1"},
                "status": {"name": "test"},
                "time": {"name": "test"}
               }]
     }
];

data.forEach(obj =>
  obj.stages.forEach(stage => console.log(stage.node.name))
);
```

Comment: with your answer, how would i add the names to a single list?

Comment: I was able to get mine working with your answer - right now I'm stuck though trying to replace console.log with adding node.name to a list (if it doesnt' already exist), I will probably make a new post for this question, but I updated the OP here anyway with the revised code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would like to print all the values for the `name` properties for each of the keys present, (ie) `node`, `status` and `time`, you could do the following,

```js
var sampleJobs = [{
  "something": "something",
  "stages": [{
      "node": {
        "name": "node0-test"
      },
      "status": {
        "name": "status0-test"
      },
      "time": {
        "name": "time0-test"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "name": "node1-test"
      },
      "status": {
        "name": "status1-test"
      },
      "time": {
        "name": "time1-test"
      }
    }
  ]
}]

// outer for loop is for the array of the job object itself
for (i = 0; i < sampleJobs.length; i++) {
 
  // inner for loop is for the stages object within the outer job object
  for (j = 0; j < sampleJobs[i].stages.length; j++) {
    // this will print each object inside the stages array 
    // console.log(sampleJobs[i].stages[j]);

    // now am making an assumption that you want to print the value for "name" property foreach of the keys, here is how you do it
    // this will print the name value for all the keys present in the object
    
  Object.keys(sampleJobs[i].stages[j]).forEach(e => {
       console.log(sampleJobs[i].stages[j][e]["name"])
    })
 
  }

}
```

**Note:** *Feel free to comment or uncomment the console statements which i have placed here as they are all for undertanding purpose only.*